# How to efficiently calculate average time between events in two tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, query-optimization

I have two tables/models:

- causes
- effects

Both have timestamps from when they were created.

I want to show: "Average time after cause until effect"

To do this by hand, I would look at the last 10-20 Effect records, and then for each I would look for the newest Cause record that is older then the given Effect. I would then average the time difference of each.

**What is the most elegant way to calculate this programmatically?**

I'm worried that as the data set grows, this could become very expensive to calculate if I don't set it up in a smart way.

In case it's relevant, I'm using Ruby 2.x + Rails 4.2 + MySQL/SqLite3 but an acceptable answer can be general / pseudo-code. In other words, I don't need you to write the query for me. Just help me figure out the smartest design pattern.

**Update**

I'm working on an approach inspired by the comments and the first answer...

I'm adding a `last_cause` column to the Effect table that contains the ID of the most recent Cause.

Comment: Why are cause and effect not related (e.g. a casue has many effects)? this would make the logic much easier just pull a cause and then determine duration to its effects. e.g a butterflies wings might be the cause and the effect might be a tsunami but I doubt the effect would be a nuclear explosion. Right now the disparate relationship of cause to effect may have nothing to do with one another based on your question. What if an effect took months to occur from a cause? Right now you are attributing that effect to the newest cause not the appropriate one

Comment: @engineersmnky The models I described in the question are simplified. The relationship between the real-lief models is more ambiguous. I probably _could_ do as you say and associate them directly with one-another... but it's not so clear in real-life which one actually relates to another. My real example is more like this: Model 1 = Beer. Model 2 = Urination. Drinking beer is definitely correlated with urination. But it feels awkward for the Beer model to hasOne Urination. Nevertheless, I want to show ave time after drinking beer until urinating. Does this help?

Comment: if you are afraid of data sets grow maybe you should do calculations in DB. Modern DBs designed for this.

Comment: @sig Can you clarify what you mean? I'm not afraid of the data growth. I'm looking for an efficient way to calculate.

Comment: i meant that u should do all calculations on DB side, with sql

Comment: in that case you dont need to return dataset to ruby and do some manipulations. Calculate all you need with sql and return result of calculations to your rails app.

Comment: @sig I'm totally open to this approach. But I don't know how to match each cause with each effect using SQL

Comment: can you provide table structure(schema)?

Comment: @sig For the purposes of this question you can assume that each table has only 3 columns: updated_at (timestamp), created_at (timestamp) and user_id (foreign key). The average I'm calculating is for specific users.

Comment: i can assume a lot of sings... but question will become more abstract. For me its looks quiet simple. One sql query, smtn like: select causes limit n join effects return average(effect.time - cause.time). All calculations will be done on database side, so you dont need to return dataset from DB to ruby and create a lot of ruby objects after, and you dont need to write any ruby's logic. Also aggregation in DB is more faster than in ruby.

Comment: @sig the "assumption" about the columns exactly matches my schema. I have one other column that specifics the `type` of the cause / effect. I omitted it so as to keep the example minimal. Will your SQL query return the same results as the ActiveRecord version suggested below? `effect.time - cause.time` looks like it's calculating something slightly different...

Comment: its not a query, its a "query plan"

Comment: assume that such a query can be written ;)

Comment: @sig ok great. Can you submit an answer showing how to do it? In case it isn't clear, this is exactly what I want to do. I just don't know how to do it with SQL. Specifically the part "effect.time - cause.time"

Answer (score 0):

What is being encouraged in the comments is setting up an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) between Cause and Effect.

```
class Cause < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :effect
end

class Effect < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cause
end
```

Then you can do things like:

```
beer = Cause.first
beer.effect
# => Urination
```

and rework Cause:

```
class Cause < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :effect

  def time_til_effect # instance method
    self.effect.created_at - self.created_at
  end
end

beer.time_til_effect
# => 30 minutes
```

You could then add a class method to Cause which will return the average time across all instances of Cause:

```
def self.average_time_til_effect # class method
  cause_effect_times = Cause.all.map { |cause| cause.time_til_effect }
  cause_effect_times.inject(:+) / cause_effect_times.length
end
```

You could go further by adding a parameter to the class method limiting its scope to the latest (x) Causes.

After saying all of that, I think the biggest takeaway is going to be checking out all of the ActiveRecord associations, they are really powerful and provide a ton of utility.

Comment: ActiveRecord is slow

Comment: btw its can be one-to-many or many-to-many. Its not described in question

Comment: @sig, I agree, just made an assumption there